# displaying data from mysql where if value is in database show true if its not show false

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

My overall goal is if there is a Value pull in ID then change the cell where ID matches the number

e.g.  the below data has been pulled in change cell 1,120,17,40,61,69,70,81,82,9 green and the rest of them red.

if there is something i need to change mysql side then let me know i did try it so that it got entered into the database from node red to say if where number between 1-100 is present in mqtt feed add value present to column present if it isnt in the feed add value false but i couldnt get that to work.

Data

```
[{"id":"1","present":"present","date":"2018-07-17","time":"10:53:20"},
{"id":"120","present":"present","date":"2018-07-17","time":"10:54:24"},
{"id":"17","present":"present","date":"2018-07-17","time":"10:53:40"},
{"id":"40","present":"present","date":"2018-07-17","time":"10:53:27"},
{"id":"61","present":"present","date":"2018-07-17","time":"10:53:14"},
{"id":"69","present":"present","date":"2018-07-17","time":"11:02:01"},
{"id":"70","present":"present","date":"2018-07-17","time":"10:53:17"},
{"id":"81","present":"present","date":"2018-07-17","time":"10:56:50"},
{"id":"82","present":"present","date":"2018-07-17","time":"10:59:28"},
{"id":"9","present":"present","date":"2018-07-17","time":"10:53:15"}]
```

PHP

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');
$servername = "localhost:3306";
$username = "user";
$password = "password!";
$dbname = "test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
#   header('Content-Type: applicaton/json');

$sql = 'SELECT 
* 
FROM test.test where time > NOW() - interval 30 minute group by id';
$result = $conn->query($sql);


$result = mysqli_query($conn ,  $sql);
$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  $rows[] = $r;
}

echo json_encode($rows);
$conn->close();
?>
```

HTML side

```
  <script>    
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        var row = $('<tr>').appendTo("#zoning tbody");
        for (var j = 1; j < 11; j++) {
            $(`<td class='${i * 10 + j}'>${i * 10 + j}</td>`).appendTo(row);
        }
    }

    $.get('php/test.php', function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        var row;
        response.forEach(function(item, index) {
            console.log(item);
    if (item.id == "notNULL") {
         return $('td.coloured').css('background-color','green').toggleClass('coloured');
        } else {
          return $('td.coloured').css('background-color','red').toggleClass('coloured');
        }            });
    });


        function updateTable() {
        //console.log('function called');
        $('td.coloured').css('background-color','#8F8F8F').toggleClass('coloured');
        $.get('php/test.php', function(response) {
            response.forEach(function(item, index) {
                console.log(item.beacon);
                //$('td.coloured').css('background-color','#8F8F8F').toggleClass('coloured');
    if (item.id == "notNULL") {
         return $('td.coloured').css('background-color','green').toggleClass('coloured');
        } else {
          return $('td.coloured').css('background-color','red').toggleClass('coloured');
        }                
    });
        });

    }
    var updateTableInterval = setInterval(updateTable, 40000);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<table id='zoning'>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There are two places where you do `if (item.id = present) `. Do you really want to assign `present` to `item.id`? It should be `if (item.id == present) ` shouldn't it?

Comment: so my goal is if ID is present in the database in the past 5 minutes change the cell to green and if it isnt change it to red

Comment: you're assigning instead of comparing.

Comment: All items in your JSON have numeric ID - but in JavaScript you are looking for IDs equal to the string `notNULL`. The table cells that you generate do not have the CSS class `coloured` - but your jQuery selectors in the `forEach` are looking for this CSS class.

Answer (score -1):

You shlould change the if (item.id = present) to if(item.id == present) in the first one you are setting the item.id to present and that is wrong you need to test . It is just a Syntax error